# What material is Kylo Ren's helmet made of?

Tags: star-wars, kylo-ren

According to a Star Wars fandom [here](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Darth_Vader%27s_armor#Helmet), Darth Vader's helmet

> *This [helmet] had a raised ridge that ran from between his eyes to the back of his head, where it merged into the durasteel, obsidian, and plasteel of the helmet itself. In addition, it was also rumored that the helmet's already strong metallic hull had also been further strengthened via dark side alchemy, with the specific technique not being found in the database of the Rhinnal Medical Academy.*

Although unsure about the source, from the quote above, Vader's helmet is supposedly made of **Durasteel**, **Obsidian** and **Plasteel**.

So, is Kylo Ren's helmet and/or armor made of the same material as that of Darth Vader's? If not, what is it made of?

Comment: I'm 99% sure the answer is "We Don't Know". It is modelled after the Knights of Ren helmets but they are all mostly cobbled together from scavenged helmets or very rudimentary. I'd imagine it is made from whatever the First Order stormtrooper helmets were made from.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot I assumed it had to be the same as Vader's because Kylo tried to be like him-  the creepy mask, the voice, the Dark Side and everything.. so why not use the same materials as well   (°~°)

Comment: I'm sure he could have done but unfortunately as far as I am aware we have no evidence for what it is made out of yet.

Comment: "Helmetium", it's a mixture of Plastic and Pure-evil.

Comment: After Kylo repaired the mask, it was imbued with Sarrassian iron to wield the cracks and piece it together, making it stronger than the last version.

Answer (score 2):

No description is given of the specific base material for the helmet in any of the novelisations, visual novels, etc. but we do know that it's almost certainly *metal* because the pieces can be held magnetically (see below).

---

Additionally, the metal used to weld the cracks was *Sarassian Iron*, according the [*Rise of Skywalker: Visual Dictionary.*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Rise_of_Skywalker:_The_Visual_Dictionary)

[image]

The front of the helmet has a *silver* inlay, according to the [*Force Awakens Visual Dictionary*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Force_Awakens:_The_Visual_Dictionary)

[image].